# Change behavior without modifying base class

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a class, let's call it `A` with a method `foo(/*with some params*/)` . I'm already using that class in my code. Now in case some param `bar`, that I pass to the above method, has a specific value I'd like my `foo()` method to return a slightly different result.

Obviously I could create a class `B` and copy the `foo` method's code, alter it a bit to fit my needs and at runtime check the value of `bar` and decide which class to call.

Is it possible using some design pattern to make that change with the following requirements in mind: a) keep using `A` in my code (probable use an `InterfaceA` and use that instead of `A`) so I won't have to change it 
and b) don't modify the code of class `A` cause it's possible to later have a class `C` with an altered `foo()` and the another and then another...

Comment: You did not provide too many details, but it sounds like inheritance is what you need.

Comment: What more can I add to the question to make it better? By saying inheritance you mean have an interface which all classes will implement and at runtime check which one to call ? I guess that would work in my case just not sure if it's the optimal decision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define `B` which would extend the interface that `A` implemented and have `A` (or better, the interface type) as a field.

```
interface AbstractA {
   void foo(Object o);
}
class A implements AbstractA {
  @Override
  public void foo(Object o) {}
}

class B implements AbstractA {
  private AbstractA abstractA;

  @Override
  public void foo(Object o) {
    abstractA.foo(o);
    // "a slightly different result"
  }
}
```

It's an example of the decorator pattern, which, [as Wikipedia puts it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern),

> allows behavior to be added to an individual object, dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class.

Comment: Thanks! Is this the `Decorator` pattern cause I was looking at it previously

Comment: @Yes, it's the decorator pattern. I will include it in my answer. (I should have...)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Base{
    foo(param1, param...n){
        // code
    }
}

class child1 extends  Base{
    bar(param1, param2, param...n){
        super.foo(param1, param2);
        // specifi code related for child1
    }
}

class child2 extends Base {
    bar(param1, param2, param...n){
        super.foo(param1, param2);
        // specifi code related for child2
    }
}

Base ob1 = new child1();
ob1.bar(param1,param2,param..n);

ob1 = new child2();
ob1.bar(param1,param2,param..n);
```